# *args in Python in combination with numpy.add()

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2, 5.4, 6, 1.5, 9])
b = np.array([5.2, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 2])


def sum_arrays(*array: np.array):
    return np.add(array)


print(sum_arrays(*a, *b))
```

Is there a way to add two arrays together with add function, using variable arguments? I know this example is wrong, but it's just to get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is add the arrays component-wise, you can use `+`, which works on numpy arrays.

```
a + b
```

Alternatively, as you've already pointed out, you can use `np.add` instead.

```
np.add(a, b)
```

If you want to sum all of the elements in both arrays, then again the simplest solution is the best: sum them both separately then add them

```
a.sum() + b.sum()
```

There's no need to use variable arguments here; numpy handles the vectorization for you, and unpacking everything into a Python tuple is just counterproductive.